# Android Studio renaming

Tags: android, android-studio, rename

I recently renamed my Android app project in Android Studio (1.1b4) project, but am now unable to rebuild. I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: D:\AndroidstudioProjects\PcUpload\app\build\intermediates\res\release\values-sw600dp-v13
```

I renamed by right-clicking the top-level in the Project hierarchy, then selecting "Refactor...Rename".

Can anyone advise how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to rename project using refactor. You are getting that error because that project technically doesnt exsist under that directory, due to rename.

Another solution would be

- Close android studio
- Change project root directory name
- Open android studio
- Open the project(not from local history but by browsing to it)

Or follow [This youtube video!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6o9RvWw4wk)

[Or this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. So I closed Android Studio, changed the project root directory name (in Windows Explorer), re-opened Android Studio, and opened the project by browsing to the folder. Now when I try to Run/Debug the app I get: "AndroidMainifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag". AndroidManifest DOES exist, and has the correct path in "package="

Comment: And I tried cleaning and rebuilding a few times but it didn't help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package?rq=1 follow the guides here..

Comment: Please close this question if your answer has been answered.